# What's the difference between Administrator and Administrator Group in windows?

Tags: windows

What's the difference between these 2 notations in windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is a specific user, the other is a specific group. Users in the 'Administrator Group' will have the same rights as the 'Administrator' user itself. Windows needs an 'Administrator' user for a variety of processes. The Administrator is in the Administrator Group, <strike>though I believe that's more for notational convenience than actual rights inheritance.</strike>

Comment: The administator user gains most of its priviledges through being in the administrators group. The only exception (i.e. inherant to administrator) is running always elevated under UAC. Removing administaror from administrators could, in theory, cause applications that hardcode the account problems. Also note the SID (underlying id) of the administrator account is fixed--the name can change but it is always the same SID.

Answer (score 1):

administrator is a built in user account that is created by operating system bydefault and it has got full control on a specified system

but administrators is group that keep the information about the no of users and ih users can access the file and folder, and migrate the resources from on place to another place